# reledmac, reledpar : wrong numbering in pair mode

Tags: line-numbering, reledmac, reledpar

I want to publish a text in english and its translation in french in two parallel columns on an A4 document.

I manage to get well synchronized paragraphs of both languages (thanks to \autopar !), but if the numbering is good for pages 1, 3 (odd pages), it is far from satisfactory for page 2 (even pages). For page 2 the left numbering is printed betwen the two columns and touches the right one.

Am I doing something wrong in my Latex code ?

---

```
    \documentclass[10pt,oneside,french,english]{scrbook}        
    \usepackage{amsmath}        
    \usepackage{amssymb}        
    \usepackage{fontspec}        
    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} \geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=0.8cm,rmargin=0.8cm}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}        
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}        
    \setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}        
    \usepackage{babel}        
    \makeatletter        
    \addto\extrasfrench{%        
    \providecommand{\og}{\leavevmode\flqq~}%        
    \providecommand{\fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi~\frqq}%        
    }        
    \makeatother        
    \usepackage[unicode=true,        
    bookmarks=false,        
    breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=section,colorlinks=false]        
    {hyperref}        
    \makeatletter        
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.        
    \@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}        
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
    \usepackage{reledmac}        
    \usepackage{reledpar}        
    \setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.46\textwidth}        
    \setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.49\textwidth}        
    \renewcommand{\Rlineflag}{}        
    \setRlineflag{}        
    \lineation{page}        
    \linenummargin{inner}        
    \sidenotemargin{outer}        
    \firstlinenum{5}        
    \linenumincrement{5}        
    \makeatother        
    \usepackage{xunicode}        
    \begin{document}        
        \addsec{Traduction}            
        \AtBeginPairs{\sloppy}            
        \begin{pairs}            
        \begin{Leftside}            
        \beginnumbering            
        \autopar    
    \textbf{\textsc{From}} my childhood days I have been a Homoeopath;

    in fact I should not be here at all if it had not been for Homoeopathy.        
    For my mother cured herself with homoeopathic pilules from a sharp        
    attack of confluent smallpox when the orthodox medical practitioner        
    had given her up, and I was born within a week or two of her ecovery.

    As a member of a homoeopathic family, luckily for me, I escaped all

    the horror of nursery medicines, such as castor oil or Gregory's powders.

    The ideals of Homoeopathy were rather blurred while I was a medical

    student. With the foolish superiority of newly acquired knowledge

    I despised the tiny little globules, which I thought might be good

    enough for children and their simple ailments. One day I had rather

    an eye-opener. A bee disliked me and I got a nasty sting on my hand.

    It swelled, and the inflammation spread up my arm. My mother humbly

    suggested \textbf{\emph{Apis}} to me. The pain was so great that I

    took it in desperation and lo and behold ! in a few minutes verily

    all pain and swelling had disappeared. Then I remembered how the

    previous summer I had been stung on my lip, and how I had been plagued

    and humiliated and frightened by one-half my face swelling enormously,

    and the local doctor's remedies had not made the slightest difference

    for three days. That was orthodox medicine for you ! `` If only

    I knew where to learn more about Homoeopathy ! ''

    I qualified, and for several years worked strenuously as House Surgeon

    in various general hospitals, and one day I heard about a School of

    Homoeopathy in Chicago. I thereupon took a busman's holiday and went

    off to the States in the late autumn. What a voyage that was ! Stormy

    and cold and rainy ! I was cooped up in a small cabin with a young

    mother, and her baby was screaming day and night from teething pains.

    I arrived tired and worn in New York and immediately fell a victim

    to a feverish chill, due to the effects of a cold northerly wind on

    a tired-out system. There was I all alone in a foreign country, laid

    up in a big hotel with a high temperature. What was to be done ? Dim

    recollections from my childhood days came to me. `` What were the

    medicines used ? Oh, yes, I have it !'' \textbf{\emph{Aconite}} and

    \textbf{\emph{Bryonia }}\textbf{3}\textbf{\emph{x}} alternately were

    taken and in a few hours they reduced my temperature. But I was left

    with a nasty sequel, a violent frontal sinusitis, an inflammation

    of the cavities in the Bony skull, which caused agonizing pains in

    my forehead and the bridge of my nose, absolutely blinding in character.

    My one idea was to get to Chicago as quickly as possible and get treatment.

    I have very little recollection of the journey between New York and

    Chicago, even though I stopped a night at Niagara to see the world-famous

    Falls. I tried mental treatment of all sorts to ease my head, but

    nothing was any use. If anything, it got worse and worse. The moment

    I arrived in Chicago I rushed off to see one of the homoeopathic

    physicians. He was rather brusque and short with me, especially when

    I told him in my opinion high potencies could not possibly do any

    good. \textbf{\emph{2x}} or \textbf{\emph{Bx}} potencies I would grant

    him, btit anything higher— mere moonshine.

    He gave me \textbf{\emph{Nux vomica}} on my symptoms, which were,

    shortly, chill caused by dry cold wind, feeling of icy coldness all

    through body, could not get warm— even sitting in front of a radiator;

    shivering as soon as movement started, violent throbbing pain in forehead

    and nose, worse stooping, worse bending forward, worse warm room,

    headache worse slightest pressure, generally worse mornings, and withal

    there was extreme irritability, snappiness and bad temper. I was

    told: `` Take the \textbf{\emph{Nux vomica}} at night but, mind you,

    it might make you feel worse, a great deal worse, at first. I shall

    give you one dose of the 100,000th potency.'' I smiled unbelievingly:

    `` I was no fool, I thought the high dilution could have no effect.

    I might just as well take plain sugar.

    Well, I was desperate, I didn't want an operation, which was the only

    other alternative for the pus in my frontal sinuses. So in the evening

    I swallowed my \textbf{\emph{cm.}} powder.

    A very short time afterwards my head felt as if there was a forge

    inside, such a violent hammering and throbbing and heat—it was like

    hell let loose. I thought every minute I was going to die with the

    agony of the pain and prayed for deliverance, when suddenly after

    half an hour, or may be an hour, there was blessed relief. The pain

    left me as suddenly as it had started. I slept all night long. In

    the morning I got up and tried to stoop and bend forward, which I

    had been unable to do for several days, and I was free from all discomfort.

    I sang `` Hallelujah, Hallelujah.'' Twenty-four hours later I took

    another dose of \textbf{\emph{Nux cm.}} as there was a slight return

    of the headache and also some difficulty in stooping. I hesitated

    for fear of starting another aggravation; but this time there was

    relief at once and no increase of pain at all.

    I had learnt two things at one go. First, that high potencies work

    rapidly and efficaciously, and secondly, that they can cause acute

    pain and aggravation and should be used with great care. Two valuable

    lessons indeed. From that day to this I have had no return of frontal

    sinusitis and, indeed, \textbf{\emph{Nux vomica}} has been a stand-by

    and valuable help in other cases of acute sinus trouble after colds

    and nasal catarrhs, both in low potencies (1\textbf{\emph{x}}) and

    high potencies, whenever indicated.

    To continue the story of my conversion to the use of high potencies.

    I was cured of my acute frontal sinus, but I found I still had a dull

    heavy feeling all over my head and I could not apply myself at all

    to any useful work. I could not read for any length of time, I could

    not remember what I read even; and this heavy stupid feeling was always

    worse between 10 in the morning and 3 in the afternoon. What particularly

    worried me was my bad memory, due to not having had a holiday for

    several years and much over-study. One of my fellow students in Chicago

    offered to cure me of my cerebral anaemia, and I was only too glad.

    She advised me to take \textbf{\emph{Tuberculinum}} 1,000th potency,

    to be repeated in weekly doses. I think I took the 1,000th potency,

    three doses. Anyway the result again was not far from miraculous.

    I could read without effort, without being plagued by headaches and,

    what was better, I could remember what I had read. In fact afterwards,

    having read a page once or twice over, I could repeat it word by word

    by heart, an achievement I had not been able to accomplish for several

    years. Again, a high potency had worked wonders. Are you surprised

    I tried high potencies on other people ? I find that high potencies

    go deeper and act longer; that is, they act for longer periods and

    they powerfully stir up the constitution and make a vital difference

    in the character, temperament and mental make-up of the respective

    patients.

    But a word of warning is not out of place here. Let me impress upon

    lay people that `` high potencies '' are not for them to play with.

    A knowledge of metaphysics, mental philosophy and logic, is necessary

    before one can hope even humbly to understand their action from a

    distance. I have been horrified at some people who after reading a

    book or two on Materia Medica, while they are still in a state of

    mental indigestion, start to throw their weight about and begin to

    treat their friends and acquaintances with repeated doses of high

    potencies, frequently changing the remedies every few days; In their

    foolish ignorance and vainglory they do more harm to the cause of

    homoeopathy than if they kept to the ordinary run of household remedies.

    Let each man stick to his own lasts; the study of medicine and still

    more the study of homoeopathy is a whole-time and life-long occupation.

    There are many others, I am fully aware, who having grasped the inner

    meaning of homoeopathy are competent to d\&al with many of the ailments

    which beset us on our path through this world of sorrow, without having

    passed through college and hospital and without possessing a medical

    qualification. But high potencies although on the othter end of the

    scale are far removed from the material toxic doses, can .kill just

    as surely as poisonous doses of opium, strychnine, etc. High potencies

    are Vibrations of the life forces of a medicinal agent, and just as

    a glass has been known to crack when a certain chord is struck on

    a musical instrument, so the silver cord attaching the higher bodies

    to the coarser grained physical body in men, may snap across, `if

    the most similar medicine is given in a very high potency.

        \endnumbering

        \end{Leftside}

        \begin{Rightside}

        \beginnumbering

        \autopar

        \selectlanguage{french}%

    Depuis les jours de mon enfance, je suis une homéopa\-the; en fait,

    je ne serai pas ici du tout si elle n'y avait pas eu l'Ho\-méo\-pa\-thie.

    Pour ma mère elle-même guérie avec des pilules ho\-méo\-pa\-thi\-ques

    d'une attaque brutale de variole confluente lorsque le médecin orthodoxe

    l'avait abandonné, et je suis née une ou deux semaines après son rétablissement.

    En tant que membre d'une famille se soignant par l'homéopathe, heureusement

    pour moi, j'ai échappé à toutes les horreurs des médicaments de pouponnière,

    comme l'huile de ricin ou les poudres de Gregory.\\

    ~

\selectlanguage{english}%

\selectlanguage{french}%

    Les idéaux de l' Homéopathie étaient plutôt floues alors que j'étais

    une étudiante en médecine. Avec la supériorité insensée des connaissances

    nouvellement acquises je méprisais les minuscules petits globules,

    que je pensais peut-être assez bon pour les enfants et leurs maux

    simples. Un jour , je devais cependant ouvrir les yeux. Une abeille

    ne m'a pas aimé et j'ai reçu un méchant aiguillon sur ma main. Elle

    gonfla, et l'in\-fla\-m\-ma\-tion s'étendit à mon bras. Ma mère

    humblement me suggéra Apis. La douleur était si grande qu'en désespoir

    de cause je le pris et voilà ! en quelques minutes en vérité toute

    la douleur et l' enflure avaient disparu. Puis je me suis souvenu

    de l'été précédent j'avais été piqué sur ma lèvre, et comment j'avais

    été en proie et humilié et effrayé par la moitié de mon visage gonflement

    énormément, et les remèdes du docteur locale avaient pas fait la moindre

    différence pour trois jours. Ce fut la médecine orthodoxe pour vous!

    ``Si seulement je savais où en apprendre davantage sur l' Homoeopathie

    !''\\

    ~

    \selectlanguage{english}%

    \selectlanguage{french}%

    Je me suis qualifiée, et pendant plusieurs années travaillé avec acharnement

    comme chirurgien dans divers hôpitaux généraux, et un jour j'entendu

    parler d' une école d'Ho\-mé\-opa\-thie à Chicago.Je pris alors

    un séjour d'une busman et est allé off pour les États de la fin de

    l' automne. Quel voyage ça a été! Orageux et froid et pluvieux! Je

    suis enfermée dans une petite cabine avec une jeune mère et son bébé

    criais jour et nuit de douleurs de dentition.\\

    ~

    \selectlanguage{english}%

    \selectlanguage{french}%

    Je suis arrivée fatiguée et usée à New York et suis immédiatement

    tombé victime d'un frisson fébrile, en raison des effets d'un vent

    du nord froid sur un système fatigué-out.Il y avait, je toute seule

    dans un pays étranger, mis dans un grand hôtel avec une température

    élevée. Que fallait-il faire? Souvenirs Dim de mon enfance sont venus

    à moi.\textquotedbl{}Qu'est - ce que sont les médicaments utilisés?Oh,

    oui, je l' ai ! \textquotedbl{}Aconit et Bryonia 3 x alternativement

    ont été prises et en quelques heures , ils ont réduit ma température.

    Mais je suis resté avec une suite méchant, une sinusite frontale violente,

    une inflammation des cavités dans le crâne osseux, ce qui a provoqué

    des douleurs atroces dans mon front et le pont de mon nez, absolument

    aveuglante caractère.\\

    ~

    Ma seule idée était de se rendre à Chicago aussi rapidement que possible

    et obtenir un traitement. J'ai très peu de souvenirs du voyage entre

    New York et Chicago, même si je me suis arrêté une nuit à Niagara

    pour voir le monde célèbre Falls.J'ai essayé un traitement mental

    de toutes sortes pour soulager ma tête, mais rien n'était toute utilisation.Si

    quoi que ce soit, il a empiré et pire. Le moment où je suis arrivé

    à Chicago je me suis précipité hors de voir l' un des médecins homéopathes.Il

    était un peu brusque et court avec moi, surtout quand je lui ai dit

    , à mon avis hautes dynamisations ne pouvaient faire du bien. 2x ou

    dynamisations Bx Je lui accorder, btit quoi que ce soit simple moonshine

    - supérieur..\\

    ~

    Il m'a donné Nux vomica sur mes symptômes, qui étaient, peu de temps,

    froid causé par le vent sec et froid, sensation de froid glacial tout

    à travers le corps, n'a pas pu obtenir même réchauffement assis en

    face d'un radiateur; frissons dès que le mouvement a commencé, douleur

    lancinante violente dans le front et le nez, pire en se baissant,

    se penchant en avant, pire pièce chaude, des maux de tête pire moindre

    pression, le matin généralement pire, et en même temps il y avait

    une irritabilité extrême, snappiness et mauvaise humeur.On m'a dit:

    \textquotedbl{}Prenez le Nux vomica la nuit , mais, voyez - vous,

    il pourrait vous faire sentir pire, beaucoup pire, dans un premier

    temps. Je vais vous donner une dose de la puissance 100.000e \textquotedbl{}.Je

    souris, incrédule: «Je suis pas fou, je pensais que la dilution élevée

    pourrait avoir aucun effet. Je pourrais tout aussi bien prendre du

    sucre brut..\\

    ~

    Eh bien, je suis désespéré, je ne voulais pas d' une opération, qui

    était la seule autre alternative pour le pus dans mes sinus frontaux.Donc

    , le soir , j'avalé ma cm. Poudre..\\

    ~

    Un très peu de temps après ma tête était comme s'il y avait une forge

    à l' intérieur, un tel martelage violent et lancinante et à la chaleur

    , il était comme l' enfer lâché.Je pensais que chaque minute que j'allais

    mourir avec l'agonie de la douleur et prié pour la délivrance, quand

    tout à coup , après une demi - heure, ou peut - être une heure, il

    y avait un soulagement béni.La douleur m'a laissé aussi soudainement

    qu'elle avait commencé.Je dormais toute la nuit. Le matin , je me

    suis levé et a essayé de se baisser et de se pencher en avant, que

    j'avais été incapable de le faire pendant plusieurs jours, et je suis

    libre de tout inconfort.Je chantais «Alléluia, Alléluia.\textquotedbl{}

    Vingt-quatre heures plus tard , je pris une autre dose de Nux cm.

    Car il y avait un léger retour des maux de tête et aussi de la difficulté

    à se pencher.J'ai hésité , de peur de commencer une autre aggravation;

    mais cette fois il y avait un soulagement à la fois et aucune augmentation

    de la douleur du tout..\\

    ~

    Je l'avais appris deux choses en une seule fois. Tout d' abord, que

    les puissances élevées fonctionnent rapidement et efficacement, et

    d' autre part, qu'ils peuvent causer de la douleur et de l' aggravation

    aiguë et doivent être utilisées avec beaucoup de soin.Deux précieux

    leçons en effet. De ce jour - là à ce que j'ai eu aucun retour de

    sinusite frontale et, en effet, Nux vomica a été une aide de stand-by

    et précieux dans d' autres cas de problèmes de sinus aiguë après les

    rhumes et catarrhes nasales, à la fois dans les basses puissances

    (1 x) et hautes dilutions, chaque fois indiqué..\\

    ~

    Pour continuer l'histoire de ma conversion à l'utilisation des hautes

    dilutions. Je fus guéri de mon sinus frontal aiguë, mais je trouve

    que j'avais encore un lourd sentiment terne partout dans ma tête et

    je ne pouvais pas me demander du tout à tout travail utile.Je ne pouvais

    pas lire , pour toute longueur de temps, je ne me souvenais pas ce

    que je lis même; et ce sentiment stupide lourd était toujours pire

    entre 10 le matin et 3 l'après - midi.Ce qui m'a inquiété était ma

    mauvaise mémoire, en raison de ne pas avoir eu un jour férié depuis

    plusieurs années et beaucoup plus d'étude.Un de mes camarades de classe

    à Chicago a offert de me guérir de mon anémie cérébrale, et j'étais

    trop heureux.Elle m'a conseillé de prendre Tuberculinum de la puissance,

    être répétée à des doses hebdomadaires.Je pense que je pris la puissance

    1000e, trois doses.Quoi qu'il en soit le résultat a été à nouveau

    pas loin du miracle. Je pouvais lire sans effort, sans être en proie

    à des maux de tête et, ce qui était mieux, je pouvais me rappeler

    ce que j'avais lu.En fait suite, après avoir lu une page une fois

    ou deux fois, je pourrais le répéter mot par mot par cœur, un exploit

    que je ne l' avais pas été en mesure d'accomplir depuis plusieurs

    années.Encore une fois, une forte puissance avait fait des merveilles.

    Êtes-vous surpris J'ai essayé hautes dynamisations sur d' autres personnes?

    Je trouve que les hautes puissances vont plus loin et agissent plus;

    qui est, ils agissent pour de plus longues périodes et ils remuent

    puissamment la constitution et de faire une différence essentielle

    dans le caractère, le tempérament et le maquillage mental des patients

    respectifs..\\

    ~

    Mais un mot d'avertissement n'est pas superflu ici. Permettez-moi

    de faire comprendre aux laïcs que «hautes puissances» ne sont pas

    pour eux de jouer avec. Une connaissance de la métaphysique, la philosophie

    mentale et de la logique, est nécessaire avant que l' on peut espérer

    , même humblement de comprendre leur action à distance.Je suis horrifié

    par des gens qui , après avoir lu un livre ou deux sur Materia Medica,

    alors qu'ils sont encore dans un état d'indigestion mentale, commencent

    à jeter leur poids environ et commencent à traiter leurs amis et connaissances

    avec des doses répétées de fortes puissances, changeant fréquemment

    les remèdes tous les jours; Dans leur ignorance stupide et vaine gloire

    qu'ils font plus de mal à la cause de l' homéopathie que s'ils ont

    gardé pour le commun des remèdes maison..\\

    ~

    Que chacun en tenir à sa propre dure; l'étude de la médecine et plus

    encore l'étude de l'homéopathie est un tout-temps et de l'occupation

    de la vie..\\

    ~

    Il y a beaucoup d' autres, je suis pleinement conscient, qui , après

    avoir saisi le sens profond de l' homéopathie sont compétents pour

    deal avec de nombreux maux qui nous assaillent sur notre chemin à

    travers ce monde de douleur, sans avoir passé par l' université et

    de l' hôpital et sans posséder une qualification médicale.Mais les

    hautes dynamisations bien que sur l'extrémité othter de l'échelle

    sont très éloignées des doses toxiques matérielles, peuvent .kill

    doses aussi sûrement que toxiques de l' opium, la strychnine, etc.

    hautes dilutions sont Vibrations des forces de la vie d'un agent médicinal,

    et tout comme un verre a été connu pour se fissurer quand un certain

    accord est frappé sur un instrument de musique, de sorte que le cordon

    d'argent à fixer les organes supérieurs à la plus grossière grainé

    corps physique chez les hommes, peut casser à travers, «si le médicament

    le plus similaire est donnée dans une très grande puissance.
    \selectlanguage{english}%

    \endnumbering

    \end{Rightside}

    \end{pairs}

    \Columns

\end{document}
```

Comment: First please indent the code with 4 spaces (select the text, then use the {} button, or Ctrl-K).  Secondly please make this a minimal example; remove everything that does not show the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the lenght of the example, but it needs several pages of text output to show the numbering behavior.

Comment: I have see only today this question. Please tag reledmac/reledpar next time. I will answer your quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to run your exemple, because you added blank line when you pasted the code. Please correct it in your question.

However, your problem is caused by the line

```
\linenummargin{inner}
```

Which told that the left number must be in the inner side, so on right for right pages, and on left for left pages.

You should replace it by:

```
\linenummargin{left}
```

Or just delete this line, as that is the default value.

Comment: Your suggestion solves the numbering problem. Thank you.

Comment: I have an other problem with the way reledpar does not separate  consecutive paragraphs ? In my code example I have in parallel a text in english and the same text translated in french. As french takes more lines than english  there is no separation betwwen french paragraphs and this is visually ugly. The partial solution I have found is to introduce an additional blank line at the end of each french paragraph but the numbering then become false. The naive idea to introduce a vertical space at the end of  french paragraph does not work.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong format of the code example I have provided. I will try to fix that point.

Comment: please validate the answer and vote up. For your problem, you should look on the § 5.2.2 of reledpar handbook and on the file 3_reledpar_sync_setting-xxx of this folder https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/examples. Or please contact me directly in French by mail.